# Can you put Try & Except clauses into List Comprehension or implement a substitute?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, sublist

How do you create a list of sublists from a different list of sublists that follows this logic:

- if the item in the sublist is a sublist itself pull only the second third item and turn it to a string. What I mean by 'item in a sublist is a sublist itself' is in the case in which there is a sublist within sublist within a sublist.
- if the item in the sublist is not a sublist, just turn it into a string

Original list:

```
 [['24000.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['24000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['9000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['6000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['15000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['15000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['3000.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['600.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['1800.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['6600.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['11000.0', [item1,item2,'Bobby Fish']], ['8000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['4000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['2500.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['3000.0', [item1,item2,'Abraham Lincoln']], ['20000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['12000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']], ['3000.0', [item1,item2,'George Washington']]]
```

Desired List:

```
  [['24000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['24000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['9000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['6000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['15000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['15000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['3000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['600.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['1800.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['6600.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['11000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['8000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['4000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['12000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['2500.0', 'George Washington'], ['3000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['20000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['3000.0', 'George Washington']]
```

Originally, I had this code, which does what I want, but this doesnt work for when the items are sublists themselves since I only want the second item in those cases.

```
lst = [[str(subli[i]) for i in range(2,len(subli))] for subli in qa[sf.records:]]
```

I figured out the code that does what I want it to, but it is twice as slow as a list comprehension so I'm wondering if there would be a way to make this a list comprehension or anyway to make it faster. The issue is implementing the try and except statements within a list comprehension

```
    Lst = []
    for subli in qa[sf.records:]:
        Sublist = []
        for item in subli[2:]:
            try:
                Sublist.append(str(item[2]))
            except IndexError:
                Sublist.append(str(item))
        Lst.append(Sublist)
    print Lst
```

which produces:

```
[['24000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['24000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['9000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['6000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['15000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['15000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['3000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['600.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['1800.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['6600.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['11000.0', 'Bobby Fish'], ['8000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['4000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['12000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['2500.0', 'George Washington'], ['3000.0', 'Abraham Lincoln'], ['20000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['12000.0', 'George Washington'], ['3000.0', 'George Washington']]
```

I would appreciate any speed improvements to the code above.

Comment: `item in the sublist is a sublist itself`, what?

Comment: I don't understand the question in the context of the sample data. It appears that all items have the same structure (`[numberstring, [item1, item2, string]]`), but you're asking something about exceptions and handling different kinds of data. It's not clear what the issue is, so I can't suggest anything. Can you cut your sample data down to something that shows the different formats you need to deal with (without a ton of redundancy)?

Comment: Essentially, I want to turn this:  ([numberstring, [item1, item2, string]]), into this:  ([numberstring, string]). The only way I can do this is by using 'try' in order to try to take the third item of [item1, item2, string]] and then use except in case you can't do this for when it's just numberstring. I just think there must be a better way.

Comment: Is the format of each sublist always `[numberstring, [item1, item2, string]]`?

Comment: well, most of the time. i was hoping that the code would be flexible enough to take in code that's organized like this as well [[item1, item2, string],numberstring] or even like this [[item1, item2, string],[item1, item2, string],numberstring], but you answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of each sublist always `[numberstring, [item1, item2, string]]` then this should work:

```
lst = [ [ str(subli[0]), subli[1][2] ] for subli in qa[sf.records:] ]
```

If the sublist is arbitrarily long and has either kind of item in it, you should modify your code to just test if the sublist item is a list or not (and look at all items), like:

```
Lst = []
for subli in qa[sf.records:]:
    Sublist = []
    for item in subli:
        if isinstance( item, list ):
            Sublist.append( str(item[2]) )
        else:
            Sublist.append( str(item) )
    Lst.append(Sublist)
```

The try/except will take a lot of time when the exception path is taken; a test is faster.